# Pre-Hilbert space and its completion

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, hilbert-spaces

I'm currently managing to understand how to find a completion of Pre-Hilbert space $\mathcal H_0$ in Stein's real analysis. The textbook says the completion $\mathcal H$ has three properties, and the proof of the second one (ii) $(f,g)_0 = (f,g)$ whenever $f,g \in \mathcal H_0$ is written on the red line as follows.

[image]

This is where I'm stuck on. The following proof is what I've tried at most.

$|(f_n-f, g_n-g)| \le ||f_n-f||_H ||g_n-g||_H$, and since  $||f_n-f||_H \to 0$ and $||g_n-g||_H \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, $|(f_n-f, g_n-g)| \to 0$. Thus $lim_{n \to \infty}(f_n,g_n) = (f,g)$.

This is what I've interpreted the definition of $(f,g)$ written on the red line. If this is correct, what should I do to induce $(f,g)_0$? The above proof doesn't include no inner product of $\mathcal H_0$, $(,)_0$, so I have a difficulty associating my trial with $(,)_0$.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I think it should read: $(f,g) := \lim_{n \to \infty} (f_{n},g_{n})_0$. Also note that $(\cdot,\cdot) \neq (\cdot,\cdot)_{0}$, but $(\cdot,\cdot)\vert_{H_0} =(\cdot,\cdot)_0$.

Comment: I've also tried your definition, and then things get much clear. Then, are you saying that Stein's comment about the definition of $(f,g)$ is just a typo and using your definition is OK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will write this as an Answer so the question can get closed.

Yes. It is just a typo.